# LESS The Dynamic Style sheet language not working after publishing website online

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, less

I am using LESS The Dynamic Style sheet language in my web site.
When i debug my website from visual studio 2010 it works fine for my local system.
But when i publish my web site upload it to web server.
It doesn't apply any Css style to web pages.
Can any one tell me how can i use less style sheet for published web site.

Answer (score 2):

LESS files have to be compiled to CSS in order to be used by the browser, which may not be happening here. LESS is similar enough to CSS (depending on the features you're using), and browsers are typically forgiving enough when processing malformed CSS, that some of the styles may be working correctly, even though the LESS isn't being compiled.

Verify compilation using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or any of the browser-based debug tools (F12 in IE, Network tab, start capture, examine the response body for the .css file you're interested in, and make sure it's valid CSS, not .less).

Also, make sure that you're not using a cached version of the CSS when viewing the site via the VS debug server. (An easy way to verify this is to enter "Private browsing mode" in your browser, which shouldn't use anything from your cache.)